# PowerApps -> Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, onedrive, powerapps

I have a PowerApp which is connected to Excel (OneDrive Business).
I want to write some Data to a table.
The problem are the `DateTime`.

If I choose for example "07.03.2021 01:00" in the DatePicker/TimePicker the "correct?" format is created für the Update-Field (I didn't change anything in the Update Formula).
But in Excel is a funny number written: 1615075200000
I tryed to format the cells in Excel as Datetime, number, text ... before writing to the cell/table nothing helps.

For some times (see ID's 1-8 in Excel screenshot) there was a datetime wrote, I don't know why.

What I have to change that the right datetime will be written to Excel, and the datetime should be displayed in excel as "07.03.2021 01:00"

[image]

Comment: Try to convert datetime in string format (if not already) then write it to excel. This way it will be treated as simple text.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak: Now I tryed to chane the Update field for the Card in the form to: ```Text(DateValue2.SelectedDate + Time(Value(HourValue2.Selected.Value); Value(MinuteValue2.Selected.Value); 0); "[$-de]dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")```, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's excel cells date-time format.

I am doing exactly as your example and the date-time updated in excel with the correct format.

Please check the below screenshots
[image]

[image]

Can you verify the Excel sheet date format?

Comment: Thx for answer. The "best" result I get is to format the Excel-Cell as "TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm" or "TT/MM/JJJJ hh:mm" (german notation). After saving in PowerApps in the cell appears a DateTimeTimezone, but this is a Text not a date value "2021-02-28T23:00:00.000Z". If I write a normal date in the Excel-Cell like "28.02.2021 17:00" PowerApps doesn`t interpret this as datetime and the (Edit)-Form doesn`t show da date in the datepicker.

Comment: I builded a compleate new App an Excel-File ... but there is the same problem.

Comment: Hey @chris ,  I have updated the date-time format in excel to dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm and it is recognized as a date in the datepicker of the power app and when update the date and save it, its reflected to excel with correct date format, and its recognized as date not as text.

Comment: Thx for feedback. I'ed try it with another account but there are the same issue. As you connect the first time to the Excel-Table, did you have some data in the table, or was it empty? I tried it with an empty table, but in this case I could not set the field as a date/time field. Only if I had some date in the column(s), PowerApps defined it as date/time and I could use the date picker. But always the same, if I submit the form in the Excel-Cell  is a datetime witten like this "2021-03-31T22:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Hey @chris ,   Please try with new excel and put one sample of date in the date time field.